# My While loop isn't working in python

Tags: python

My while loop is not repeating even though the sentry value has not been met to break the loop. Please help.The while loop looks to me like to should not break until varaiable computernumber is equal to number

```
import random
print("Hello and welcome to the AI guessing Game pick a number from 1 to 100 then press H or L to give the clue")
number=input("pick a number from 1 to 100")
number=int(number)
tries = 0
computernumber=1
while computernumber !=(number):
    computernumber=random.randint(1,100)
    print (computernumber)
    higherorlower=input("is your number higher or lower use H or L please!")
    if higherorlower == "H":
        computernumber +=1
        tries = int(tries)
        tries +=1
        computernumber=random.randint (computernumber,number)
    else:
            computernumber -=1
            computernumber=random.randint (1,computernumber)
            tries = 0
            tries = int(tries)
            tries +=1
            print (computernumber)

            break

if computernumber == number:

    if tries == 1 or 0:

        print("Your number was", number,"and it took me",tries,"Try")
    else:
        print("Your number was", number,"and it took me",tries,"Tries")
```

Comment: Is this how you code is actually indented, or just how it was pasted in SO?

Comment: it was pasted the indentation was correct

Comment: Fix the indentation so it's identical to what you're running. What you have here wouldn't run, it would just throw an indentation error.

Comment: The code as you have pasted contains a syntax error in the while loop. If that's your error, the error message should be helpful and straightforward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `computernumber=random.randint(1,100)` this will take random number in range(1,100) in every iteration.. Thats why you should not put it inside your loop
2. `break` in `else` will break the loop. thats why your loop is not repeating.

Modified code:

```
import random
print("Hello and welcome to the AI guessing Game pick a number from 1 to 100 then press H or L to give the clue")
number=input("pick a number from 1 to 100 :")
number=int(number)
tries = 0
computernumber=1

# Bring it outside of your loop.
computernumber=random.randint(1,100)

while computernumber !=(number):
    print (computernumber)
    higherorlower=input("is your number higher or lower use H or L please!")
    if higherorlower == "H":
        computernumber +=1
        tries = int(tries)
        tries +=1
        computernumber=random.randint (computernumber,number)
    else:
            computernumber -=1
            computernumber=random.randint (1,computernumber)
            tries = 0
            tries = int(tries)
            tries +=1

            # Do not use break here
            #break

if computernumber == number:
    if tries == 1 or 0:

        print("Your number was", number,"and it took me",tries,"Try")
    else:
        print("Your number was", number,"and it took me",tries,"Tries")
```

Comment: Thanks i didnt notice im 13 only just started python

Answer (score 0):

I had to modify a few things in your program to get it to work.  I added a function for the random number and added an M option for match so the loop ends.  I also needed to change the input function to raw_input.  This is because input modifies the content whereas raw_input gets the input exactly as typed.

```
import random

def getRandomNumber( minimum, maximum ):
  return random.randint( minimum, maximum )

print( "Hello and welcome to the AI guessing game.  Pick a number from 1 to 100 then press H or L to give the clue.\n" )

number = int( raw_input("Pick a number from 1 to 100: ") )
tries = 0
computernumber = 0

# min and max random numbers initially
minimum = 1
maximum = 100

while computernumber != number:
  tries = tries + 1
  computernumber = getRandomNumber( minimum, maximum )

  print (computernumber)

  higherorlower = str( raw_input("Is your number higher, lower, or a match?  Use H, L, or M please! ") )

  if higherorlower == "H":
    computernumber +=1
    minimum = computernumber
    maximum = number
  elif higherorlower == "L":
    computernumber -=1
    minimum = 1
    maximum = computernumber
  elif higherorlower == "M":
    computernumber = number # this ends the loop on a match

if computernumber == number:
  if tries == 1 or 0:
    print("Your number was", number,"and it took me",tries,"Try")
  else:
    print("Your number was", number,"and it took me",tries,"Tries")
```